# ajax http post giving error 500 when sending json

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, json, http-post

I'm trying to send json data as text with a HTTP POST method in ajax to a controller in my MVC4 project. This is my ajax code:

```
function saveService() {
        var data0 = $("#nameInput").val();
        var data1 = generateJSON();
        var data2 = $("#wellContainer").html();
        var jsondataobject = { name: data0, counter: counter, json: data1, html: data2 };
        var stringobject = JSON.stringify(jsondataobject);
        console.log(stringobject);

        console.log(data1);
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'text',
                url: "http://localhost:49162/Admin/SaveNewTemplate",
                data: "jsonData=" + stringobject,
                success: function (returnPayload) {
                    console && console.log("request succeeded");
                },
                error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                    console && console.log("request failed");
                },

                processData: false,
                async: false
            });
    }
```

This is my controller method

```
[HttpPost]
public void SaveNewTemplate(String jsonData)
{
    DataAccessLayer DAL = new DataAccessLayer();
    DAL.SaveServiceTemplate(jsonData);
}
```

This is my error in the console:

```
POST http://localhost:49162/Admin/SaveNewTemplate 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

My stringobject is a correct json object converted to a string. If i replace this variable in the ajax function with some random text it works.

Why do i get the 500 error?

Comment: i'm getting same kind of error.Did you get any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be an issue with the jsondataobject being sent. All objects should be with quotes:
{ "name": data0, "counter": counter, "json": data1, "html": data2 }

Also:
 data: "jsonData=" + stringobject,
should be:
data: stringobject,

(assuming variable counter is being populated correctly too as it is not mentioned in the code snippet)